# How to listen for gestures/screen touches inside a service w/o activities

Tags: android, android-service, foreground-service, gesturedetector

I have a service running as a foreground service (using a notification) and wanted to know what is the current (nowadays) best way to listen to gestures / screen touch events in that service.
I don't have nor want to have an activity or any UI visible elements.

Thanks.

I'd prefer some other way other than Accessibility Service

Comment: That is not generally possible, for obvious privacy and security reasons. You are welcome to explore implementing an accessibility service, but you might also wish to discuss your plans with a qualified attorney.

Comment: @CommonsWare From reading here and there on the internet it used to be possible with some sort of system alert or overlay trick. Just haven't found my way yet. You are going way further with your legal assumptions than the question implies. For the moment I just want to build an app for me so talking with an attorney is not needed yet.

Comment: "From reading here and there on the internet it used to be possible with some sort of system alert or overlay trick" -- a lot of that has been locked down, once again for privacy and security reasons.